# Bootstrap Glyphicons temporarily rendered as rectangles

Tags: google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

When I leave our application open, after a while all Glyphicon instances will look like this:

[image]

Moving the cursor over the buttons will instantly bring back the correct images:

[image]

Is there a specific reason for this? From what I can tell, we're really not doing anything special. I've seen this happen on two workstations already.

Comment: Are you using fontawesome?

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12475253/1686330

Comment: @DirkLachowski: I saw a couple of questions related to the icons *always* being rendered as rectangles. But this is only temporary. :(

Answer (score 0):

I have had the exact same problem. I solved it by using CDN's instead of local files.

I'm not saying its a solution - im just saying you might be able to isolate the problem that way.

Comment: Our application runs in a closed local network. There is no access to a CDN and there are no bandwidth-related issues.